# The difference phase of two sine signal processing

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I was pointed to detect phase shift of two sine output of homemade circuit.But I have some problem with trigonometry function. Assuming model X = A*sin(B) + C, A and C can be calculated by means and standard deviation. It's still large than 1(I think the standardization or normalization likes z-core method will break the statistic properties of a sine signal, so I do not use it).

But the difference phase is almost a chaos, it may be a constan with some ups and downs. Then I use hilbert transform and unwrapped phase, it still unwork. I have used all my knows.

From above, Is some misunderstanding in my way, or just too simple(do not use complete information fo two signal)?  Can somebody tech me or recommand some books/blogs/papper for me?

Thanks

Comment: Do the signals have the same frequency?